# Search the Keywords present in the title

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables

1.products fields

```
1.product_id
2.product_title,
3.product_desc
4.product_img
```

2.keywords fields

```
1. id
2. keyword
```

keywords will be

```
 1.hair
 2 body
 3 tv
 4 mobile
```

product_title will be

```
1. Hair oil
2. Hair Straightner
3. Body oil
4. Body massage
5. LCD TV 32"
6. LED TV 40"
7. Air conditioner
8. Washing machine
9. Refrigrator
```

According to the keyword present in the title it have to show listing, for here it have to show products from 1 to 6 ,it should not show the 7 to 9. How I can do it?

Comment: The best thing to do is add a table productsToKeywords that will allow you many to many relationship between the 2 tables

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, The best thing to do is add a table `productsToKeywords` that will allow you many to many relationship between the `products` and `Keywords` tables.

```
create table productsToKeywords
(
    ptk_product_id int foreigm key reference products (product_id),
    ptk_keyword_id int foreigm key reference keywords (id),
    primary key(ptk_product_id, ptk_keyword_id)
)
```

Then your select would look something like this:

```
select product_id, product_title,, product_desc, product_img
from products 
inner join productsToKeywords on(product_id = ptk_product_id)
inner join Keywords on(ptk_keyword_id = id)
where keyword = 'hair'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
  select p.* from Product p
    inner join Keyword k
    on p.product_title like '%' + k.keyword + '%'
```

If it is possible to have `empty` values in keyword or title fields, then you need to add condition to ignore such records too. Otherwise it would match with all.

Comment: Actually, null values will never match. however, if a keyword can be an emtpy string, then it will match all.

Comment: @ZoharPeled thanks for pointing out. I meant a keyword resulting in `%%` but wrote null. Have corrected that.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `EXISTS` like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM products p
WHERE EXISTS( SELECT 1
              FROM keywords k
              WHERE p.product_title Like '%' + k.keyword + '%')
```