# How do I setup keywords in this case?

Tags: database, ms-access, database-design

I am making a DB that will hold drawings / files / notes or links to these items. Then I'm making a program that will let a user type in a keyword and it will give them the links to the drawings/ files/ or notes. But I'm not sure how to store all the keywords and still have it fast enough to work.

```
Example Table Main
ID  Area  Type  Specific  File  Keywords
1   RX1    icc   tester   ..    Lock, SG1, Va2, CN1, CN2, SGP, Vu, Boof
2   RX1    ECU   tester   ..    SG1 , BA3, yys, yyz, yyx, Lock
3   RX3    ECU   Control  ..    SG2, SG3, VA2, YYS
etc....
```

So a user would select area then type then specific, and type in a keyword to get the results. There are about 10,000 rows.  And the keywords could be anywhere from 1 to 200.

Second can this be done in MS Access db? I know Access has limits but it's what I already have installed and am used to working with.

Comment: You say the user types in 'a keyword' implying just one keyword.  That's straight-forward.  If you decide to allow the user to type multiple keywords, you'll need to consider whether that's an AND (intersection) operation or an OR (union) operation, and how to provide grouping and negation too.

Comment: i belive ill make it just one, as the db is used to return drawings with the keyword they enter..the keyword is usually an error name. and usually we just need the first error on the list to get the drawings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't keep the keywords in the main table. Instead, keep a keyword table and a fileToKeyword table for a many to many relationship. 
Then you will have no limit to the number of keywords for each item.

Your primary key for this table should be both columns (fileId, keywordId) and your search would be a 3-table join.

[I answered a similar question yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31154196/3094533)

Table examples per your request in the comments:

```
Table Main
----------
ID  Area  Type  Specific  File
1   RX1    icc   tester   ..
2   RX1    ECU   tester   ..
3   RX3    ECU   Control  .. 

Table Keywords
--------------
Keyword_Id  Keyword_Text
1           Lock
2           SG1
3           Va2
4           CN1
5           CN2
6           SGP

Table FileToKeyword
-------------------
FileId   KeywordId
1        1
1        2
1        3
1        4
1        5
1        6
2        1
2        3
```

**Notes:**
In keywords table

- Keyword_Id is the primary key
- Keyword_Text is unique

In FileToKeyword table

- FileId is a foreign key to table main
- KeywordId is a foreign key to table keywords
- The combination of both columns is the primary key

Your select should look like this:

```
SELECT ID, Area, Type, Specific, File
FROM Main
INNER JOIN FileToKeyword ON(ID = FileId)
INNER JOIN Keywords ON(KeywordId = Keyword_Id)
WHERE Keyword_Text IN('Lock', 'SG1')
AND Area = 'RX1'
-- any other conditions you might want to add
```

Comment: But if I used just the one table then the area/type would narrow down the results it would have to search threw. We're as if I just had the one table I would have to seach lots of data each time. And the key word might be same but it would still have to fit the area / type

Comment: Sorry not a pro at sql, any chance you could show a small example of the tables?  I dont understand the file to keyword table and how it would work

Comment: I'll try to do it today, perhaps tomorrow

Comment: Thanks,  I am still trying and might see what you mean.. of course i am sure there is a way to do one db query to get the results where i have it in 3 lines  https://paste.ee/p/LXxbD

Comment: Great Answer Its very clear now, Thanks for your time